# execute code 3 time when the condition is limit to 2

Tags: laravel

I have tables `Coupon` and `Coupon_usages`.

```
$userTimesRedeemed = CouponUsage::where('coupon_id', $coupon->id)->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

if ($coupon->usage_limit_per_user<$userTimesRedeemed->count()) {
    return response()->json([
        'is_valid' => false,
        'message' => 'Coupon has already been used max number of times.'
    ], 422);
}
```

Initially the `Coupon_usages` table is empty so when add:

```
$coupon->usage_limit_per_user = 2;
```

And run the code it will execute 3 times.

How to avoid this error?

**Note**: initally the `Coupon_usages` table is empty.

Comment: Did you check this value $userTimesRedeemed->count()

Comment: What about `if ($userTimesRedeemed->count() && $coupon->usage_limit_per_user < $userTimesRedeemed->count())`?

Comment: yes initally there is no value return because the table is empty

Comment: i want to execute my code even if the table is empty and the usage_limit_per_user under the limit
but instead it execute limit+1 times

Answer (score 0):

```
$userTimesRedeemed = CouponUsage::where('coupon_id', $coupon->id)->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

if ($coupon->usage_limit_per_user <= $userTimesRedeemed->count()) {
    return response()->json([
        'is_valid' => false,
        'message' => 'Coupon has already been used max number of times.'
    ], 422);
}
```

Add `<=` in your condition because if your count is 2 and limit is 2 then

```
if($coupon->usage_limit_per_user<$userTimesRedeemed->count()) // it will return false
```

because 2 is not less than 2
you should check less then or equals to 2

Comment: what is the coupon_usage is empty initiall?'

Comment: when you count it will return 0